# CSS creating evenly spaced table using divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a collection of boxes each 50% width with margins that collapse to create even spacing but also fit into place beside each other.

Something like:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/b1a9L7fa/

```
<style>
body{
 margin:0;
}
.showCases{
 background-color:#000;
 overflow:auto;
}
.showCases>div{
 width:50%;
 margin:20px;
 color:#fff;
 border:1px solid #fff;
}
</style>
<body>
 <div class="showCases">
  <div>
   box1
  </div>
  <div>
   box2
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Is there a way to do this with just a parent div and child div? Or do I have to create grandchild div?

Comment: Do you want in one line ??

Comment: Use padding to space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get something like this with `Flexbox` if you set `margin` on flex-items and then same amount of `padding` on flex-container. That will create same spacing between each flex-item and parent and flex-items

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.showCases {
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}
.showCases > div {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="showCases">
  <div>box1</div>
  <div>box2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: lets say I have 4 boxes that are 50% each. Two on top and two on bottom. How do I use flex for this situation?

Comment: isn't `display:table` with `table-layout:fixed` the optimal solution?

Comment: I don't see any spacing.

Comment: i did not style my solution. updated my posting. also created it on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m2e6t8je/

Answer (score 3):

Use `display:table` and add `table-layout:fixed` -> all cells have same width

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
.trow {
  display: table-row
}
.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="trow">
    <div class="tcell">cell 1</div>
    <div class="tcell">cell 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="trow">
    <div class="tcell">cell 3</div>
    <div class="tcell">cell with more text 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution, +1.

Comment: The problem with this is that you need to create a row every time you want to add more cells. Or lets say you have a media query and you want to have 3 or more cells if you resize the screen. Its hard if they are stuck inside rows, but its easy if they are based on a percentage with without a restrictive row element. But +1 since I learned something

Answer (score 1):

Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/b1a9L7fa/1/ ?

```
.showCases>div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc( 50% - 44px);
  margin: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to remember when aligning blocks;

1. The combined widths (including margins) cannot be greater than 100% combined (as a general rule, there are exceptions). Don't forget, without box-sizing: border box, borders and padding count in this width too!
2. When you want two elements to place themselves next to each other, you need to tell them so using display: block and float: left, or use display: inline-block.

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b1a9L7fa/3/

```
body{
 margin:0;
}
.showCases{
 background-color:#000;
 overflow:auto;
}
.showCases>div{
 width:46%;
 margin:20px;
 margin-right: 2.5%;
 margin-left: 2.5%;
 color:#fff;
 border:1px solid #fff;
 display: block;
 float: left;
}
.showCases>div:last-of-type{
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer without twice the size of margin in between the divs! You win @Lewis! :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flexbox grid to evenly split your boxes.

Just add those two rules to your CSS:
https://jsfiddle.net/8v0qmk1h/

```
.showCases{
    display: flex;
}

.showCases>div{
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: The gap in the middle is larger than the outer gaps. More css would be required to fix that.

Comment: Yes, theres extra space between. Also, lets say I want a grid of 4 boxes, two on top and two on bottom, how can I use flex for this?

Comment: @Lewis Good Point, to fix that give the child divs just a margin-left and the .showCases>div:last-child the needed margin-right

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
display:inline-block
width:calc(50% - 44px);
```

on child div

https://jsfiddle.net/b1a9L7fa/4/